# what query to write that there are only "three"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| aa | one |
| aa | one |
| bb | two |
| bb | two |
| cc | three |

select distinct

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| aa | one |
| bb | two |
| cc | three |

What query to write that there are only "three"?

Comment: Some data in plain text and expected outcome would be helpful.

Comment: `select distinct a, b from t` ?

Comment: This question is far too unprecise. Lots of queries will produce this result for this sample data. And likely most of them would fail for other sample data. You need to explain in detail what you want to do and show possible edge cases to take care.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following provide the expected result?

```
select a, b
from t
group by a, b
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT a, b
FROM
   table;
```

I think this will result in what you need, yet the question is unclear. If this query does not solve your issue please clarify more what you need.

Comment: That's just a pure copy of The Impaler's comment above